# Twilio Voice conference from Browser using PHP

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-conference

I have successfully implemented Voice calls functionality in my php application using JS SDK.

Now, I need to implement Call Monitoring and barge in features, that I believe are only available using Twilio Conference.

My current code looks like

```
$response = new VoiceResponse();
$dial = $response->dial('');
//If Incoming call, redirect the call to my browser client
if($phonenumber == $mytwiliophonenumber)
{
 $dial->client($browserclientname);
}
//If outgoing, make the call to the phone number
else
{
 $dial->number($phonenumber);
}
```

Now, what is the easiest way to change this to conference?

I have read that I need to dial the conference, but it is not working.

```
$dial->conference('anyconferencename');
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conference has a fundamental difference to connecting two callers together in a regular `dial`. A conference acts as a room that participants join individually, rather than when you use `client` or `number` which places an outbound call leg to the client or number you are dialling.

If you have your user dial into a conference using `$dial->conference` you will need to create another leg to call the other person into the conference too. You can do this using the [conference participants API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-conference-participant&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x).

So, instead of your current code, you could update to something like this:

```php
$response = new VoiceResponse();
$dial = $response->dial('');
//If Incoming call, redirect the call to my browser client
if($phonenumber == $mytwiliophonenumber)
{
  $participant = "client:" . $browserclientname;
}
//If outgoing, make the call to the phone number
else
{
  $participant = $phonenumber;
}

$conferenceName = 'conferencename';
$twilio->conferences($conferenceName)
                      ->participants
                      ->create($mytwiliophonenumber, // from
                               $participant, // to
                      );
$dial->conference($conferenceName);
```

In this option, regardless of whether the call is inbound or outbound, the caller is placed in a conference call. And another call is generated to add the other participant to the conference call too.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to place an outgoing call (conference) with the other party, yet to test the incoming part, where the other party calls the Twilio number. 

Three questions - 
1. The conference didn't end when the other party ended the call at their end.
2. How do I change the background music until the call is answered by agent?
3. How can a supervisor monitor this call / listen in to this call?

Comment: 1. You'll need to set [`endConferenceOnExit`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-endConferenceOnExit) to be true. 2. You can set a [`waitUrl` to control hold music](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-waitUrl) (yes, the default music is bad, you should change it ). 3. You'll want to look into the coaching features known as [Agent Conference](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/agent-conference-generally-available.html) for monitoring, coaching and barging in.

Comment: I updated the code to add endConferenceOnExit, still the conference ends only when agent ends, not when participant ends.

$dial->conference($conferenceName,['startConferenceOnEnter' => 'true', 'endConferenceOnExit' => 'true']);

Comment: You'll need to set [`endConferenceOnExit` for the participants you add via the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-conference-participant&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x#participant-properties) as well then.

Comment: Thanks mate, waiturl worked. Still struggling with ending the conference when the participant ends my outgoing call to them. Is it because I am adding the participant and myself in the same conference create function call? Do I need add the participant separately?

Comment: Might be a good idea to ask a new question and share the code you are now using.